# c# class scope, and object creation

Tags: c#

cant quite understand how class work

```
 class Class1{
             private int a;
                 for(a=0;a<10;a++){}
// how can a be out of scope?


             }
```

and why i can do this

```
class Class1{
             private int a;
             void tera()
              {
               private string aiha="lk"; //commenting this out ,makes it work why??
               for(a=0;a<10;a++){}
               }
             }
```

1st part : can a class have only methods and fields? why?

2nd  part:  cant methods have declarations?

i know this might be a poor explanation but i cant wrap my head around .

Comment: First example has a for loop outside any method. Not allowed, Second example has a private access modifier added to a local method variable. It makes no sense and it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st.

(Classes are basic constructs of .NET Framework.)

Because it's object oriented  it can only contain **MEMBERS** like methods, fields, constants, properties, and events  as single units .
(note: also members  must be declared within a type).

2nd

In C# there are no global variables or methods as there are in some other languages.

and i think since c# considers a method as a single object you cannot try give different access to its variables,  it will think you are trying to create another member for the class.

Answer (score 0):

For the  first part,  you haven't defined a method name so it wont work, you can't place the method's body inside a class without declaring a method.

```
class Class1{
      private int a = 0;
      void Example() {
         for(a=0;a<10;a++){}
       }

             }
```

Would work

For the second part, it  wouldn't  make sense as variable is  only  available inside the method's scope so its  meaningless to give it a modifier.

You  can  read more about classes [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-class-and-object/) but basically  its  a  group of members and methods that are usually gonna be used every time you create an  instance  of that class.